# JMeter writing multiple entries to jtl file for 1 transaction

Tags: apache, jmeter

I am having trouble with getting accurate results from the JTL file that NON-gui mode jmeter outputs.

I have a **transaction controller** that generates a parent sample and when I run the transaction, the resulting jtl file has a single entry, which I expect.

`1513634189384,1552,Test Login Controller,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 1, number of failing samples : 0",Client 1-1,,true,4314,1,1,0`

When testing the script on a remote machine, I expect a single entry in the JTL file with the host name:
example:
`1513634189384,1552,Test Login Controller,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 1, number of failing samples : 0",Client1-1,,true,,4314,1,1,MY-HOST`

However, the resulting JTL file has 3 entries, 1 of which is expect.
Resulting output:

```
 1513634189384,1552,Test Login Controller,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 1, number of failing samples : 0",Client 1-1,,true,4314,1,1,0  
 1513634189384,1552,Test Login Controller,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 1, number of failing samples : 0",Client 1-1,,true,,4314,1,1  
 1513634189384,1552,Test Login Controller,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 1, number of failing samples : 0",Client 1-1,,true,,4314,1,1,MY-HOST
```

Why are the other 2 entries getting written and from where?

I am on Jmeter 3.0. 
My **properties** are:

```
# legitimate values: xml, csv, db.  Only xml and csv are currently supported.
#jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv


# true when field should be saved; false otherwise

# assertion_results_failure_message only affects CSV output
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=true

# legitimate values: none, first, all  
#jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results=none

#jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=true   
#jmeter.save.saveservice.label=true  
#jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true  
# response_data is not currently supported for CSV output  
#jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=false  
# Save ResponseData for failed samples  
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true  
#jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true  
#jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true  
#jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true  
#jmeter.save.saveservice.time=true  
#jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=true  
#jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=true  
jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=false  
#jmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time=false  
#jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=false  
#jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=false  
#jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=false  
#jmeter.save.saveservice.encoding=false  
#jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=true  
#jmeter.save.saveservice.url=false  
#jmeter.save.saveservice.filename=false  
jmeter.save.saveservice.hostname=true  
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=true  
#jmeter.save.saveservice.sample_count=false  
jmeter.save.saveservice.idle_time=false
```

Comment: You may appending to file several execution, try to delete the jtl file, and check results after 1 execution

Answer (score 0):

1. You might be writing the results into the same .jtl file. You can add `-f` argument to your JMeter startup script to ensure JMeter deletes existing .jtl results file before test execution.

   ```
   jmeter -n -f -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```

   More information: [Full list of command-line options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
2. You might have > 1 remote machine so JMeter actually executes the test on 3 slaves therefore you have 3 entries in the result file. You can try adding [__machineName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineName) or [__machineIP()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) function to the name of your Transaction Controller like `Test Login Controller - ${__machineName()}`

   [image: JMeter Function Append hostname to results]

   This way you will see from which machine request is coming from in the .jtl results file. See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article to learn more about JMeter Functions concept.
3. You simply have > 1 thread or loop defined in [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

Comment: So I've run through all 3 options to be sure and I am still seeing the same issue. Looking at the logs in the remote server, I see this being fired 3 times.

`2017/12/20 05:33:30 DEBUG - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Firing sample 
2017/12/20 05:33:30 DEBUG - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Firing sample 
2017/12/20 05:33:30 DEBUG - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Firing sample`

To clarify also, I am running the thread group once. My loop count is set to 1

Comment: This issue seems to only happen now when running the test in NON gui mode.

Answer (score 0):

MY testing sites was https
and I made empty in jmeter. so it considered as http by default.
For this setting i receiver multiple entry in log file.
After i changed to https in jmeter for my test case.
Multiple entry in log file issue got solved.